# Angular 2 Router error : Always redirect to home

Tags: angular, typescript, module, routes

I'm created angular 5 application and it's debugging without any compile error.
It worked before.In that time I used only one route.ts file and one app.module.ts file for whole project.Then I realized It'll more complex when project getting bigger.Then I just changed my folder structure.Now every time I go to other urls it redirect to home page.

about my folder structure, I have created separate app module and route module for each functions as below. Home page and login page has different layouts.
my auth routes handle by **auth-routing.module.ts** and it imports to **auth.module.ts**.
I **have app-routing.module.ts** to handle main routes and it imports for **app.moduele.ts**

My folder structure

[image]

auth-routing.modules.ts

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { NoAuthGuard } from '../auth/no-auth-guard.service';
import { HomeAuthResolver } from '../layout/home-auth-resolver.service';

import { AuthComponent } from '../auth/components/index';

const routes: Routes = [  
    { path: 'login', component: AuthComponent},
    { path: 'register', component: AuthComponent }       
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
    ],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AuthRoutingModule { }
```

**auth.module.ts**

```js
import { ModuleWithProviders, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { AuthRoutingModule } from './auth-routing.module';
import { AuthComponent} from './components/index';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [     
    AuthComponent          
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,    
    AuthRoutingModule   
  ],
  providers: [ ]     
})
export class AuthModule { }
```

**app-routing.module.ts**

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { NoAuthGuard } from './auth/no-auth-guard.service';
import { HomeAuthResolver } from './layout/home-auth-resolver.service';

import {LayoutComponent,  PUBLIC_ROUTES } from './layout/index';

const routes: Routes = [ 
    { path: '', component: LayoutComponent, data: { title: 'Secure Views' }, children: PUBLIC_ROUTES },
    { path: '**', component: LayoutComponent, data: { title: 'Secure Views' }, children: PUBLIC_ROUTES }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
    ],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

**app.module.ts**

```js
import { ModuleWithProviders, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

//modules
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AuthModule } from './auth/auth.module';

// Layouts
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { LayoutComponent, HomeAuthResolver } from './layout/index';

//child components
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';

//shared components
import { ApiService, AuthGuard, FooterComponent, HeaderComponent } from './shared';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    FooterComponent,
    HeaderComponent,
    LayoutComponent,
    HomeComponent,

  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,   
    AuthModule
  ],
  providers: [
    ApiService,
    AuthGuard,
    HomeAuthResolver,
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: You have not loaded the feature module routes to the main router configuration. You need to lazy load auth routes into app-router. Check this docs for more info. https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules

Comment: what is role of auth.module.ts class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You not export `AuthRoutingModule` in `auth.module.ts`.

change `auth.module.ts` to this :

```
import { ModuleWithProviders, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { AuthRoutingModule } from './auth-routing.module';
import { AuthComponent} from './components/index';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [     
    AuthComponent          
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,    
    AuthRoutingModule   
  ],
  exports: [AuthRoutingModule],
  providers: [ ]     
})
export class AuthModule { }
```

and remove `CommonModule` usage from `auth-routing.module.ts`.

like this:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { NoAuthGuard } from './auth/no-auth-guard.service';
import { HomeAuthResolver } from './layout/home-auth-resolver.service';

import {LayoutComponent,  PUBLIC_ROUTES } from './layout/index';

const routes: Routes = [ 
    { path: '', component: LayoutComponent, data: { title: 'Secure Views' }, children: PUBLIC_ROUTES },
    { path: '**', component: LayoutComponent, data: { title: 'Secure Views' }, children: PUBLIC_ROUTES }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
    ],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Comment: @isanka this  is helpful for you?

Comment: please remove CommonModule in your routing modules imports and check

Comment: and remove RouterModule import from app.module.ts

Comment: it's working after I removed CommonModule  from auth-routing.module.ts. Thank you.. can you please edit your answer and it'll help to others..